# What are all the rumors villagers can spread about you and what do they mean?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

When I talk to a villager in town, sometimes they say something like

> Oh! Rumor has it you're a bell pincher!

Or when your visiting a dream town a villager will say

> The mayor here is such a time traveler!

I was wondering what all the rumors about your character are and what they mean. I know some like being called a Bell Pincher (you don't spend much and you have tons of money) or being called a Time Traveler (you change the clock settings a lot). But recently I've been called a "Hometown Hero" and I have no idea what that means.

So what are all the rumors that can spread around you, and what do they mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This page has a list of all the rumors in New Leaf and how you get them (scroll down to the New Leaf section to see them): https://animalcrossing.fandom.com/wiki/Reputation

Specially, the hometown hero one you mentioned is from having a high approval rating.

Comment: Whats an approval rating?

Comment: @Ari - First of all, the approval rating is how good your town is. A good approval rating is a perfect town. Second, reputations/rumors don't change any actual gameplay except for the fact that most of your villagers will call you the rumor on your first interaction on that day or if you haven't talked to them for a while.